# Java Graph library for Network visualization by Graph

Tags: java, graph, visualization, graph-visualization, jung2

I want to Implement a visualization interface for visualizing `nodes` and `edges` as graph and some objects like nodes moving between the nodes as **Data packets** Like the image below:

[image]

I have tried using the **Jung** library but it lacks any kind of feature for moving objects between the nodes using the edges as the *path* for the moving object.
I have seen the demo of Graph Stream Library that shows some objects moving between nodes but when I looked at the library documentation I didn't find any feature for moving things in the graph , Is this library capable of my need?

If not can anybody suggest a library that can provide me such functionality.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT :   Further efforts in implementation**

I am already implementing such functionality in **JUNG** and for straight edges it works fine , I am using the `IterativeProcess` class and moving the nodes by `setLocation` function.

[HERE](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:49d8) is the implementation.

But I was wondering is there really a better way of doing this by some other library that has some internal defined functionality for doing such thing?

Comment: This looks cool, but asking for library recommendations is against the rules.

Comment: But There are many other questions asking about the libraries.

Comment: You should flag those to be closed.  They don't belong here.

Comment: You might consider asking at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Andreas Should I remove it from here? , I have already set a bounty.I have also added the coding efforts.

Comment: I would keep it for now. Did you check out [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com)? They seem to focus on a Web (Javascript) based library now, but the Java (Swing) library is still available as JGraphX at https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx

Comment: I checked it , it seems there is no feature implemented for movement in graph.I will keep digging , Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think for your requirement a visualization tool is more suitable than a graph library. I've already used [Processing](https://processing.org/) tool in my visualization course which is based on java. It is so simple and easy to learn and still powerful.